# Long-lived tokens for a business user account on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We trying to make updates to FB pages from an external system.

In order to use the Facebook API an access token is required.

We are able to get a short-lived access token by using the Facebook API Explorer. The short-lived token lasts about 2 hours.

Based on what we have read, it is possible to get a long-lived token which lasts about 60 days however this must be done programmatically and only Facebook Applications.

The typical FB App acts like a Web page asking for permission to access a user's account and do things with that account. In order to request a long-lived token you must include an Application’s key and secret key.

As a personal user we are able to register as a Facebook developer, create a 'dummy App' and successfully generate a long-term token to use.

The issue is, we are a business user. The Facebook account is a business account as opposed to a personal account and you cannot create an Application for that account.

Since we can’t have users create and use a dummy App for a business type account we don’t have a way to generate a long-lived token in that case.

Why doesn't FB allow apps for business accounts? Or more importantly, does anyone know how to generate a long lived token for a FB business account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no reason a business account can't get a long-lived access token, that's one of the primary purposes of business accounts, managing ads and pages via the API

Only real, verified, personal users should be the owner/developer/admin of an app, but an app's users don't necessarily need to be regular users.

There's a bug right now about business accounts not being able to get 60 day tokens. That bug excluded, business accounts should be able to get 60 day tokens the same way a personal user does.

Comment: Hi Igy, do you know when the bug might be addressed?

Comment: It was addressed weeks ago; if you don't get a 60 day token, try uninstalling the app from that user's profile completely (a HTTP DELETE request to `/<USER ID>/permissions` with their user access token or your app access token will do this) and send them through the server-side oauth flow again: The user may have authorised your app before the auth dialog supported long-lived tokens, in which case they still get short-lived